# How to serve same functionality with different layouts in a Symfony2 app?

Tags: symfony, twig

I have in a Symfony2 application the following bundle architecture:

- `CommonBundle`
- `FirstBundle`
- `SecondBundle`

Several features are implemented in the `CommonBundle`.
These features have to be available in the 2 other bundles.

The `FirstBundle` and `SecondBundle` have therefore their own features + the ones of the `CommonBundle`. These bundles each have their own host defined in the main application `routing.yml` file.

**What I'm trying to do:**

Features of the `CommonBundle` should be displayed with the layout of the current bundle.

For instance, if I hit `http://firstbundle.myapp.com/common/feature1`, I should see the layout of the `FirstBundle` bundle.

And if I hit `http://secondbundle.myapp.com/common/feature1`, the layout of the `SecondBundle` bundle should be used.

How can I do that?

I can't use bundle inheritance as the same bundle can't be extended twice.

In my current implementation, each bundle imports the routes of the `CommonBundle` in its own host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a controller response listener and change the template name depending on the request hostname in there.

A good read is the [How to setup before/after filters](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html) chapter of the documentation.

You could aswell use a twig extension registering a global variable and decide which template to extend inside your base template:

config.yml

```
services:
    twig.extension.your_extension:
        class: Vendor\YourBundle\Twig\Extension\YourExtension
        arguments: [ @request ]         
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension, alias: your_extension }
```

YourExtension.php

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class YourExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
   protected $request;

   public function __construct(Request $request)
   {
        $this->request = $request;
   }

   public function getGlobals()
   {
       // some logic involving $this->request

       $baseTemplate = ($this->request->getHost() === 'first.host.tld') ? 'FirstBundle::base.html.twig' : 'SecondBundle::base.html.twig';

       return array(
          'base_template' => $baseTemplate,
       );
   }

   public function getName()
   {
       return 'your_extension';
   }
```

base.html.twig

```
{% extends base_template %}
```

Comment: I like the idea!

Given that the templates of common features are located in the `CommonBundle` bundle, would that mean that I should send a parameter to the view for all requests, and that these common templates would decide which layout to extend depending on that paramter?

Comment: You could either solve it using a parameters which indicates which template to extend ... or change the used template name in the listener - if hostname = second.* -> replace FirstBundle with SecondBundle in `FirstBundle:Controller:Action.html.twig`. The parameter solution could be achieved in a twig extension registering a global aswell !

Comment: I actually don't have any templates in the FirstBundle and SecondBundles concerning the common features.
So I guess I'm going to write a Twig extension as you said that determines which layout to extend for templates in the CommonBundle, based on the host. It doesn't look very beautiful, but will work fine. I will let you know!

Comment: ping did you solve the puzzle? did my answer help? if yes please upvote/accept otherwise leave a comment :)

Comment: Thanks @nifr, I ended up implementing your solution!